# PostgreSQL Transaction to Use Results from Query to Insert and Query another Table then Return Original Query Results

Tags: postgresql

I am writing an application that stores data on file samples and YARA signatures.  Essentially, in a single transaction, I need to execute a query, reference those results in an insert and another query, then return the original results. I have three tables that are relevant to this discussion:

1. samples - this is the table that stores information on files that need to be scanned with the associated YARA signatures.
2. yararules - the table that stores information on the YARA rules.
3. yaratracker - a table that tracks the sample/rule pairs that have been processed thus far.

In a single transaction, the application needs to:

1. Get a batch of unique sample/rule pairs that have not yet been processed. Preferably, this query will get all non-processed rules associated with a single sample (i.e. if I'm going to run the YARA rules on a sample, I want to run all of the YARA rules not yet processed on that sample so that I only have to load the sample into memory once).
2. Get a unique list of id,sha256 from the batch found in step 1.
3. Insert the batch from step 1 into the yaraqueue with the matchcount column equal to 0 and complete column set to false.

I can accomplish Step 1 with the query below, but I don't know how to reference those results to accomplish step 2. I've tried looking into variables, but apparently there isn't one that can hold multiple rows. I've looked into using a cursor, but I can't seem to use the cursor with a subsequent command and then return the cursor.

```
SELECT s.id,r.id
FROM sample s CROSS JOIN yararules r
WHERE r.status = 'Disabled' AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM yaratracker q
    WHERE q.sample_id = s.id AND q.rule_id = r.id
) 
ORDER BY s.id
LIMIT 1000;
```

The relevant database schema looks like this.

```
CREATE TYPE samplelist AS ENUM ('Whitelist', 'Blacklist', 'Greylist', 'Unknown');

CREATE TABLE samples (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    md5 CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    sha1 CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    sha256 CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    total INT NOT NULL,
    positives INT NOT NULL,
    list SAMPLELIST NOT NULL,
    filetype VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    submitted TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    user_id SERIAL REFERENCES users;
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX md5_idx ON {0} (md5);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sha1_idx ON {0} (sha1);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sha256_idx ON {0} (sha256);

CREATE TYPE rulestatus AS ENUM ('Enabled', 'Disabled');

CREATE TABLE yararules (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    rules TEXT NOT NULL,
    lastmodified TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    status rulestatus NOT NULL,
    user_id SERIAL REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE yaratracker (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    rule_id SERIAL REFERENCES yararules ON DELETE CASCADE,
    sample_id SERIAL REFERENCES sample ON DELETE CASCADE,
    matchcount INT NOT NULL,
    complete BOOL NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX composite_idx ON yaratracker (rule_id, sample_id);
CREATE INDEX complete_idx ON yaratracker (complete);
```

Comment: `Get a unique list of id,sha256 from the batch found in step 1.` These are all candidate keys, so you can just as well use a unique sample on `samples.id` (the primary key)  To pick only one record per sample you could use `UNIQUE ON (...)` , or `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id) rn ... WHERE rn=1`

Comment: That makes sense on how to get a unique sample list with the sha256 column, but how to return that as a separate result set from the original query. I could just pull the sha256 column with the first query and accept that the sha256 column data will be duplicated by the number of rows in the yararules table; however, that is pretty wasteful. If I pull 100K entries from the CROSS JOIN, then I'll have about 6MB worth of duplicate sha256 hashes I have to pull across the network.

Is there a way to reference the first query in a second query where I can unique the data and return it seperately?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO target_table(a,b,c,...)
SELECT sid, rid, sha, ...
FROM (
        SELECT s.id AS sid
          ,r.id AS rid
          , s.sha256 AS sha
          , ...
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id) AS rn -- <<<--- HERE
        FROM sample s CROSS JOIN yararules r
        WHERE r.status = 'Disabled' AND NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1 FROM yaratracker q
          WHERE q.sample_id = s.id
            AND q.rule_id = r.id
        )
        ORDER BY s.id
        LIMIT 1000;
) src
WHERE src.rn = 1; -- <<<--- HERE
```

---

The `WHERE src.rn = 1` will restrict the cross-join to deliver only one tuple per  `sample.id` (both `id` and `sha256` are unique in the `sample` table, so picking a unique `id` has the same effect as picking a unique `sha256`)

The complete cross-join result will never be generated; the optimiser is smart enough to push down the `WHERE rn=1` condition into the subquery.

Note: the `LIMIT 1000` should probably be removed (or pulled up to a higher level)

---

If you **REALLY** need to save the results from the CROSS JOIN, you could use a chain of CTEs (expect a performance degradation ...)

---

```
WITH big AS (
        SELECT s.id AS sample_id
                ,r.id AS rule_id
                , s.sha256
                -- , ...
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id) AS rn -- <<<--- HERE
        FROM sample s 
        CROSS JOIN yararules r
        WHERE r.status = 'Disabled' AND NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT 1 FROM yaratracker q
                WHERE q.sample_id = s.id AND q.rule_id = r.id
                )
        )
, ins AS (
        INSERT INTO target_table(a,b,c,...)
        SELECT b.sample_id, b.rule_id, b.sha256 , ...
        FROM big b
        WHERE b.rn = 1; -- <<<--- HERE
        RETURNING *
        )
INSERT INTO yaratracker (rule_id, sample_id, matchcount, complete )
SELECT  b.sample_id, b.rule_id, 0, False
FROM big b
-- LEFT JOIN ins i ON i.a = b.sample_id AND i.b= b.rule_id
        ;
```

---

NOTE: the yaratracker(rule_id,sample_id) should **not** be serials but just plain integers, referencing yararules(id) and sample(id)

Comment: This gets me closer to the overall goal, but I still need to return the entire CROSS JOIN batch.

Comment: Why do you need it? `... will be duplicated by the number of rows in the yararules table; however, that is pretty wasteful. If I pull 100K entries from the CROSS JOIN, then I'll have about 6MB worth of duplicate ...`

Comment: The sha256 and id are part of the file name on the storage array where the actual file sample itself is located. The database just stores the Metadata about the file. The program itself only needs one copy of the sha256 hash per sample.